# Showing a animated gif on Amstrad E3 that has Linux 2.6.16 on it..?

Tags: animated-gif

Trying to find a way to animated a gif on Linux 2.6.16 thats on a Amstrad E3 Emailer, Linux is just commandline no desktop or anything, the gif are the adverts that use to show on the E3 Firmware,I have 7 gifs thats I want to show on its screen one after another but don't know how I would go about it.

Comment: How does this machine draw graphics? [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xj8EHWzvqcs) it can be seen that it surely isn\`t just a CLI.

Comment: Its been hacked to run Linux 2.6.16 on it,you can update it to 2.6.19 too,but have not yet,its here [link](http://the.earth.li/pub/e3/) Because the E3 only has 32mb of ram it only has a CLI on it info about is here[link](http://amstrad-e3-hacking.freeforums.net/thread/11/flash-amstrad-mailer-video-phone) and [link](https://www.earth.li/~noodles/hardware-e3.html)

Comment: So you\`re basically asking how to enable graphics on it _and_ then display a GIF. Something tells me that the first task will prove much harder than the second one…